# How to choose row from other column in dataframe if row from the default column is NaN?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy, nan

My dataframe consists of 3 columns. The thirth column is based on the first two columns. The default column is column 2. But if column 2 is NaN, then I want column 3 to be filled with column 1. I added the third line to conditions, but it does not seem to work.

This is the DataFrame:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.array([[np.nan, 1717], [1749, 1750], [1704, np.nan]]),
                   columns=['a', 'b'])
```

This is my code:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
conditions = [
    (df["b"] <= df["a"]), 
    df["b"] > df["a"],
    df["b"] == df["b"].isna()]

choices = [df["b"], df["a"], df["a"]]

df['c'] = np.select(conditions, choices, default=df["b"])
print(df)
```

This is my output:

```
           a            b      c
0        NaN         1749.0  1749.0
1        1717.0      1750.0  1717.0
2        1704.0      NaN     NaN
```

But I want c to be filled if a or b is filled. So this is the output I want:

```
           a            b      c
0        NaN         1749.0  1749.0
1        1717.0      1750.0  1717.0
2        1704.0      NaN     1704.0
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need to make a small change to your third condition. `df["b"].isna()` already returns `True` or `False`, so `df["b"] == df["b"].isna()` is actually checking to see if `df["b"]` evaluates to the same `boolean` (it doesn't).

Just remove the first half of the third condition.

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
conditions = [
    (df["b"] <= df["a"]), 
    df["b"] > df["a"],
    df["b"].isna()]

choices = [df["b"], df["a"], df["a"]]

df['c'] = np.select(conditions, choices, default=df["b"])
print(df)
```

Comment: seems like we could use `np.where`: `df['c'] = np.where((df["b"] > df["a"]) | df["b"].isna(), df["a"], df["b"])`

Comment: That does also work; I don't know if there's a reason why one might be preferred, except people find find one or the other easier to read.

Answer (score 1):

This seems to work:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.array([[np.nan, 1717], [1749, 1750], [1704, np.nan]]),
               columns=['a', 'b'])

df['c'] = df.a

for i in range(len(df)):
    if df.a.iloc[i] == np.nan:
        df.c.iloc[i] = df.b.iloc[i]
```

Answer (score 1):

This solution gives the output that you want:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame(np.array([[np.nan, 1717], [1749, 1750], [1704, np.nan]]),
                   columns=['a', 'b'])

def fill_row(row):
    if pd.isnull(row['a']): 
        return row['b']
    else: 
        return row['a']

df['c'] = df.apply(lambda row : fill_row(row), axis=1) 
print(df)
```

The output:

```
        a       b       c
0     NaN  1717.0  1717.0
1  1749.0  1750.0  1749.0
2  1704.0     NaN  1704.0
```